# Can the Mac Mini Support a 4K Monitor?

Tags: display, mac-mini, 4k

I'm assembling my workplace and I'm looking into Mac Mini **MD387LL** along with some 4k monitor like this one, [Samsung 28-inch UHD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IEZGWI2).

Problem is that I'm not sure if the Mac Mini will support this humongous 4k resolution. Does anyone has rock solid information on that?

Comment: It supports this http://support.apple.com/kb/sp597

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you run a 4k monitor at 30hz with a late 2011 MBA?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134366/can-you-run-a-4k-monitor-at-30hz-with-a-late-2011-mba)

Answer (score 3):

**I can confirm 100% that you CAN in fact get 3840x2160 @30Hz 4K from a Late 2012 mini running 10.10.5 using only one MDP to DP cable.** I'm writing this using a 2012 Mac mini (Intel HD4000 internal graphics card + 8G ram) with Dell P2815Q 4K monitor. How I achieved this: 1) Used Mini Displayport to Displayport cable that came with the monitor - MDP/thunderbolt from Mac Mini to DP on display. 2) Ran the Mac Pixel Clock Patch for Yosemite: https://code.google.com/p/mac-pixel-clock-patch/source/clones  3) Downloaded and configured [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/srx_download/download.html), set the resolution, saved and rebooted. Hope the info helps. Enjoy!

Comment: Oh that's cool! I'll give it a try! Thanks for sharing ;)

Comment: What's your solution for High Sierra? Are you still running 4K on the Dell from Intel HD Graphics 4000 over DisplayPort?

Comment: I just plugged my 2012 mac mini to a 4k on High Sierra in 2019 and it went to 4k by default to my complete surprise. It's low refresh though, 30Hz probably.

Answer (score 1):

MD387LL has Intel HD Graphics 4000, which uses DisplayPort 1.1, with 8 Gbps maximum throughput. In theory, this could support 4k resolution at 30 Hz *(Edit: or maybe not, see comment below)* but in practice 4k support generally requires 15 Gbps.

So the answer is: unless you write your own graphics driver, 2560x1600 is the highest you can go.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Because [DP 1.1 cannot, even in theory, support 4k display at any resolution.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7049/intel-thunderbolt-2-everything-you-need-to-know). Additionally, in practice, the default refresh rate is 30 Hz, unless [Multi Stream Transport](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6008) is enabled on the 4k monitor.

Comment: Hmm. [This presentation](http://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ICCE-Presentation-on-VESA-DisplayPort.pdf#page=18) says otherwise. Perhaps there is a 2x difference between theoretical and actual performance?

Comment: Removed downvote. That's highly informative, though I can't find where it says otherwise. Under the "advantages" slide, I believe 4K support only applies to DP 1.2 (it's ambiguous in the slides). It's a matter of hardware limitations. 10Gbps bandwidth doesn't provide a large enough pipe to render 4k display @ 30 Hz. Perhaps at 24 Hz, however?? Either way, the conclusion is the same for the OP: not possible. Cheers.

Comment: @FooBar do you think they will complete the upcoming OSX bundle with those drivers? any information on that?

Comment: Loomy, I apologize for not being clearer. No, it won't happen. What I am talking about is theoretical, and may well require custom hardware modification. No one anywhere, including Intel, has done it. And Apple would say to just buy a new Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In fact if your mac mini support multi-monitor configuration (i.e. 2 monitors) and allows spanning your desktop then you **can** archive **4k@60Hz using 2 hdmi cables**. Samsung UHD has 2 hdmi ports and it supports PBP mode (http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/skp/faq/1061869). Samsung UHD monitor emulates 2 monitors (picture-by-picture mode) with resolution (**1920x2160**). As a result one hdmi cable is resposible for left part of the picture, anoher for the right part. I have not tried this on mac but yesterday tested it on PC, going to test on mac on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Did 4k on mac mini late 2009. The strange problem anohter monitor had to be connected to make icons bigger to fit the 4k, this was solved to connecting two cables to the same 4k screen, and on the screen select the port providing 4k. :) Best mini computer I ever owned back then.